# How do I compile code that uses circular references?

Tags: c++, oop, circular-dependency

I got a code of snake in c++ sfml.. I got 2 objects here Snake and Food, also I have a `main()` that contains sfml setup for windows. I would simply make 3 objects that are called from main but it results in circular references and can't compile.

What I want to have is (or something close to the idea below).

```
int main
{ 
    Food food(window); 
    Snake snake(window, food); 
    Window window(snake, food); 

    window.start(); 
}
```

snake gas method draw that needs reference to its window (for drawing as drawing needs window handle), and update whuch also needs window (for window size)

food also needs those for close reason (need draw and window suze)

window in turn has its window loop from where it need to calls those updates and draws of snake and food

//edit

someone asked for definitions but definitions are strightforward

```
    class Snake;
    class Food;

    class Window
    {
    public:
      Window::Window(Snake& s, Food& f): snake(s), food(f)
      {

      }
    private:
      Snake& snake;
      Food& food;

    }

    class Snake
    {
    public:
      Snake::Snake(Window& w, Food& f): window(w), food(f)
      {

      }
    private:
      Window& window;
      Food& food;

    }

    class Food
    {
    public:
      Snake::Snake(Window& w): window(w)
      {

      }
    private:
      Window& window;

    }
```

Comment: Use some sort of references or pointers. Don't directly contain objects, your code will compile fine. May need an extra bit of ownership management, but that's easy with `shared_ptr` now.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes

Comment: if its related where is the answer to what i state?

Comment: no it seem to be about headers and i dont get a problem with headers but with references

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that we can comment on.

Comment: its posted above its real code i wand, in constructors you simply assign references to internal fields... note i dont want to use pointers unless realy nothing else work... if i need pointers i would ask if someone would show me how (im experienced c coder but c++ newb)

Comment: definitions are strightforward, i may add them bit you may imagine them

Comment: It would seem that people are having trouble understanding what is being asked here.  I'm reading that code "cant compile", but the code shown can compile.  If you are asking why code can't compile, please show code that we can attempt to compile.

Answer (score 1):

> how to compile c++ code that has circular references?

You cannot compile C++ code that has circular references.

If you have a circular reference, the solution is to break the cycle, so that dependency graph becomes a directed acyclic graph.

There is another form if indirection in C++ besides references: pointers. Because pointers can be default initialised and assigned later, they can form cyclical structures.

A pattern that can break cyclical initialisation is two phase initialisation: First create `Food` and `Snake` with no association to a `Window`, and only after `Window` is created, call a function that performs the second phase of initialisation. Two phase initialisation cannot be used with references, but can be used with pointers.

Comment: i tried to do that but references seems need to be assigned in constructors so i cant make object with them unassigned and then assign it later...show me what exactly to do..some working piece of c++ as much close to the above as it may be, tnx

Comment: @J.Stone Therefore you cannot use references for two phase initialisation. There is another form of indirection in C++: Pointers.

Comment: so what to do ?

Comment: @J.Stone I edited the comment with a solution.

Comment: i dont see it...

Comment: @J.Stone I've now edited the answer accordingly as well.

Comment: i would better see the snippet of code